# How to unify aggregating function with Postgres per different group by

Tags: postgresql

`my_data` table is like this (one row example):

```
 total_cost | total_exp | ind1 | ind2 | ind3 | flag
------------+-----------+------+------+------+------
 1000       | 2000      | A    | A1   | A2   | F
```

And I have a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_my_aggregation() RETURNS VOID AS $$
        DECLARE
            import_date date;
        BEGIN
            FOR import_date IN
            SELECT generate_series('2005-01-01'::date, '2015-04-01'::date, '1 month'::Interval)
            LOOP
                insert into my_timeseries

                       select
--                       ind1 as ind,
--                       ind2 as ind,
                       ind3 as ind,
                       import_date,

                       -- size

                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'F' and total_exp > 0) as f_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'S' and total_exp > 50) as s_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'D' and total_exp > 100) as d_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'T' and total_exp > 20) as t_cost_a,

                       from my_data
                       where date_trunc('month', date_of_transfer) = date_trunc('month', import_date)
--                       group by ind1, import_date;
--                       group by ind2, import_date;
                       group by ind3, import_date;
            END LOOP;
        END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The expected outcome is an array aggregation with the `ind1,ind2,ind3` renamed to `ind` and the relative aggregations.

The problem with that functions is that I have to switch (and run 3 times) `select ind1 as ind....group by ind1,import_date`.

Is there a way to unify it in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`grouping sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS):

```
select
  coalesce(ind1, ind2, ind3) as ind,
  ...
group by grouping sets (
  (ind1, import_date),
  (ind2, import_date),
  (ind3, import_date));
```

But its was introduced only in [9.5 version](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#GROUPING_SETS.2C_CUBE_and_ROLLUP).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lateral` to unpivot the columns `ind1`, `ind2` and `ind3` into a single column and specify the latter as a grouping criterion:

```
select
    v.ind,
    import_date,

    array_agg(d.total_cost) filter(where d.flag = 'F' and d.total_exp > 0) as f_cost_a,
    array_agg(d.total_cost) filter(where d.flag = 'S' and d.total_exp > 50) as s_cost_a,
    array_agg(d.total_cost) filter(where d.flag = 'D' and d.total_exp > 100) as d_cost_a,
    array_agg(d.total_cost) filter(where d.flag = 'T' and d.total_exp > 20) as t_cost_a,

from
    my_data as d,
    lateral (values (d.ind1), (d.ind2), (d.ind3)) as v (ind)
where
    date_trunc('month', d.date_of_transfer) = date_trunc('month', import_date)
group by
    v.ind, import_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to concat those columns together? Is that what you need?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_my_aggregation() RETURNS VOID AS $$
        DECLARE
            import_date date;
        BEGIN
            FOR import_date IN
            SELECT generate_series('2005-01-01'::date, '2015-04-01'::date, '1 month'::Interval)
            LOOP
                insert into my_timeseries

                       select
                       ind1||';'||ind2||';'||ind3 as ind,
                       import_date,

                       -- size

                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'F' and total_exp > 0) as f_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'S' and total_exp > 50) as s_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'D' and total_exp > 100) as d_cost_a,
                       array_agg(total_cost) filter(where flag = 'T' and total_exp > 20) as t_cost_a,

                       from my_data
                       where date_trunc('month', date_of_transfer) = date_trunc('month', import_date)
                       group by ind1||';'||ind2||';'||ind3, import_date;
            END LOOP;
        END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```